# What is the significance of "removal_effects" in ChannelAttribution R package?

Tags: markov-chains, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to build a Markov model using the `ChannelAttribution` package available in `R`.

Sample code to run this model is -

```
M <- markov_model(Data, var_path, var_conv, var_value=NULL, var_null=NULL,
order=1, nsim=NULL, max_step=NULL, out_more=FALSE, sep=">", seed=NULL)
```

Source documentation says that `out_more = TRUE` option gives model's removal_effects. I would like to know the significance of this `M$removal_effects`.

If these are the weights of the input `channels` in the `Data` , then should they sum to 1 ?

I have tried to print the `sum` of these removal_effects and I get a different value every time I run the model

Source documentation - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChannelAttribution/ChannelAttribution.pdf